# How to remove white spaces between stacked geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

date <- seq(ymd('2018-08-01'), ymd('2018-08-31'), by = '1 day')
c <- 21.30
x1 <- runif(length(date), 0, 20)
x2 <- rnorm(length(date), 10, 3)
x3 <- abs(rnorm(length(date), 40, 10))
data <- data.frame(c, x1, x2, x3) %>% 
  t() %>% as.data.frame() %>% rownames_to_column('var')
data <- data %>%
  mutate(category1 = c('catA', 'catB', 'catB', 'catC') %>% as.factor(),
         category2 = c('catAA', 'catBA', 'catBB', 'catCA') %>% as.factor())
names(data) <- c('var', as.character(date), 'category1', 'category2')
data_long <- data %>% 
  gather(date, value, -var, -category1, -category2) %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date))

data_long %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = category1)) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack') +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 week', date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d', expand = c(.01, .01)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .4)) +
  labs(fill = '')
```

With the example data and code above I generate the following plot:
[image]

What I need to do is to remove white spaces between columns. I have found some similar topics, but they recommended use of `position_dodge()` while it can't be used in my case as I already have `position = 'stack'`, which can't be replaced. How can I make the columns adjacent to each other then?

## Edit

Setting `width = 1`, as proposed by @camille, seems to work ok with the raw data, but not with aggregated to weeks or months - please see the code below:

```
data_long %>%
  mutate(date = floor_date(date, unit = 'week', week_start = 1)) %>% 
  group_by(category1, date) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = category1, width = 1)) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack') +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 month', date_labels = '%Y-%m', expand = c(.01, .01)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .4)) +
  labs(fill = '')
```

[image]

## Edit 2.

As pointed out by @Camille, width of 1 may refer to 1 day in case of date scale. However, the following doesn't produce expected output and returns warning message: `position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals`

```
 data_long %>%
    mutate(date = floor_date(date, unit = 'month', week_start = 1)) %>% 
    group_by(category1, date) %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE),
              n = n()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    ggplot(aes(date, value, fill = category1, width = n)) +
    geom_col(position = 'stack') +
    scale_x_date(breaks = '1 month', date_labels = '%Y-%m', expand = c(.01, .01)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .4)) +
    labs(fill = '')
```

[image]

Comment: `width = 1`? The default, per `?geom_col`, is for width = 0.9

Comment: Seems to work ok with original data, but not with aggregated one - please see my edit.

Comment: Hi, how do I get rid of the warning `position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals`? This is really pain in the neck.

Answer (score 5):

The docs for `geom_col` are more specific than what I put in my comment above. The more detailed meaning of the width parameter:

> Bar width. By default, set to 90% of the resolution of the data.

In a general case, such as your first one, this probably just means the distance between one discrete case and another. But in the case of dates, which *have* a real resolution, this seems to refer to days. I'm not sure if there's a different way to set the resolution of the dates, such as for one unit to refer to one week, instead of one day.

I'm decreasing the alpha just to be able to see if bars overlap.

So without setting a width, this defaults to 90% of the distance between observations, i.e. 90% of one week.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
...

summarized <- data_long %>%
  mutate(date = floor_date(date, unit = 'week', week_start = 1)) %>% 
  group_by(category1, date) %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ungroup()

ggplot(summarized, aes(date, value, fill = category1)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 week', expand = c(.01, .01))
```

[image]

Setting width to 1 means the width is 1 day. I feel like there's a discrepancy here that someone else might be able to explain, why this is read as 1 day rather than 100% of the resolution.

```r
ggplot(summarized, aes(date, value, fill = category1)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.6, width = 1) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 week', expand = c(.01, .01))
```

[image]

So to get a width of 1 week, aka 7 days, set width to 7. Again, I think there's a bit of explanation someone else could fill in here.

```r
ggplot(summarized, aes(date, value, fill = category1)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.6, width = 7) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 week', expand = c(.01, .01))
```

[image]

**Edit:** Based on the [link in my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33619670/5325862), the best way might just be converting the dates to strings so you can just plot on a discrete x-scale as normal. Before you call `as.character`, you could do whatever formatting you might want.

```r
summarized %>%
  mutate(date = as.character(date)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, fill = category1)) +
    geom_col(width = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems a little weird. What about months then? Some months are of 30 days, some of 31 days and there's of course February which may have 28 or 29 days. Adding n = n() to summarise and then setting width = n doesn't help much (please see edit 2.). So how can I deal with that?

Comment: Honestly don't know, although I think your version with aggregates is going to throw things off since you're assigning a vector to width by saying `width = n`, rather than a single static number

Comment: [Here's an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33619670/5325862) for something similar, where their suggestion is just to convert the x variable to a factor (or character) and dropping the date scaling. That might be the way to go, since you could still format strings or factor labels to look like dates

Comment: It would take a bit more data prep for the stacking, but you might also consider using `geom_rect` to avoid dealing with widths at all. Then it'd work equivalently for days / weeks / months, or even for unevenly spaced time periods.

Answer (score 4):

(BTW, it can be helpful to include `set.seed()` at the top so that we all come up with same data. I used `set.seed(42)` for these.)

One alternative that can bring some more flexibility would be to use `geom_rect` or `geom_tile` instead of `geom_col`. Then you can make each bar exactly as many days/weeks/months wide as you want. But it takes a little more prep work.

As an example, here I pre-calculate the cumulative y-coordinates for each bar, by grouping by date, sorting by category2, and getting the cumulative sum. I also determine the x range from the date and by grabbing the following date. (I do have one manual bit at the end where I assume the final column on the right of the chart should be one "day" wide. Adjust if using weeks/months. There might be a clever way to use `padr::pad` or something else to automatically intuit what that increment should be.)

```
data_long2 <- data_long %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  arrange(desc(category2)) %>%
  mutate(top = cumsum(value),
         bottom = top - value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(category2) %>%
  mutate(next_date = lead(date, default = max(date) + 1)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

With this, you can use `geom_rect` or `geom_tile` to get your chart. They're interchangeable, but they use different coordinate systems, based on the corners or center, respectively.

Here's an example using `geom_rect` where each bar's left edge is aligned to date.

```
ggplot(data_long2) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = date, xmax = next_date,
                ymin = bottom, ymax = top,
                fill = category1)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 week', date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d', expand = c(.01, .01)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .4)) +
  labs(fill = '', y = "")
```

[image]

Or you might use `geom_tile`, and in this case I'm aligning with date in the middle of each bar.

```
ggplot(data_long2) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = date, width = as.numeric(next_date - date),
                y = (top + bottom)/2, height = (top - bottom),
                fill = category1)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = '1 week', date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d', expand = c(.01, .01)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = .4)) +
  labs(fill = '')
```

[image]