# Bar width or spacing is not consistent in ggplot with month on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble getting the spacing of my bars to be consistent in ggplot, when month is on on the x-axis.  Here's my code:

```
date_field = c("2017-01-01",
               "2017-02-01",
               "2017-03-01",
               "2017-04-01",
               "2017-05-01",
               "2017-06-01",
               "2017-07-01",
               "2017-08-01",
               "2017-09-01",
               "2017-10-01",
               "2017-11-01",
               "2017-12-01",
               "2018-01-01",
               "2018-02-01",
               "2018-03-01",
               "2018-04-01",
               "2018-05-01",
               "2018-06-01",
               "2018-07-01",
               "2018-08-01",
               "2018-09-01",
               "2018-10-01",
               "2018-11-01",
               "2018-12-01")

totals_field = c(12,
                 23,
                 25,
                 24,
                 3,
                 76,
                 36,
                 55,
                 55,
                 34,
                 101,
                 30,
                 53,
                 26,
                 23,
                 23,
                 276,
                 37,
                 47,
                 75,
                 100,
                 150,
                 34,
                 30)

df <- data.frame(date_field, totals_field)

df$date_field <- as.Date(df$date_field)


df_plot <- ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=date_field, y=totals_field, fill="red"), width=30, colour="white", stat="identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+ theme(
  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
                                colour = "white",
                                size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
  panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',
                                colour = "white"), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid',
                                colour = "white"),
  axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", linetype = "solid"),
  axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black", linetype = "solid")
  ) + scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))) + scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0)))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y",date_breaks = "1 year")

df_plot
```

The chart output:

[image]

As you can see, the spacing (or maybe the width?) are somewhat uneven, which I am guessing is due to how ggplot is interpreting number of days in each month, possibly?  I tried to use a solution found here:

[Inconsistent bar widths when month-scaling in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616049/inconsistent-bar-widths-when-month-scaling-in-ggplot/33619670)

But unfortunately I didn't have any luck. What can I try here? I would think setting a standard spacing for the bars would solve this problem, but it does not.

Comment: Can you show the output you are getting.  I don't find any uneven widths with that code

Comment: please see my edits, pic included.

Comment: I think that's an antialiasing issue downstream of ggplot and I suspect you are on a windows machine looking at the plot window. I think it'll go away if you change your graphics device in Global Options to AGG, or if you save the output using `ggsave(...`

Comment: I want to render the plot in rMarkdown (HTML output).  How exactly should I use ggsave?

Comment: actually, it looks fine in RMarkdown.  Thanks!

Comment: I make the plot and was with equal spacing. But if you are still having the problem, one simple solution is considering the date as factor.